# jQuery: Get all input vals within a table and serialize

Tags: jquery, serialization

Given the following table structure, how would I get all the input vals within a table when the `.button` is clicked?

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><input value="1" name="A" type="text" /><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input value="2" name="B" type="text" /><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input value="3" name="C" type="text" /><td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="button"></div><td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is the jquery I have so far:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent('table').('input').serialize());
});
```

The function isn't working though, it's not finding the input in the table I guess...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`table` is not the parent of the button, `td` is...  try :

`$(this).closest('table').find('input').serialize()`

Answer (score 1):

not very direct, but should give you the understanding:

http://jsfiddle.net/5D5NG/3/